# Can my squad mates run out of ammo?

Tags: mass-effect-3

There are powers and weapon modifications that affect the ammo capacity. I'm wondering whether those make even sense for your squad mates, if they ever run out of ammo?

Do my squad mates have unlimited ammunition or can they run out of ammo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Squadmates will not run out of ammo, **however**, the upgrades to ammo powers that increase capacity *do* carry over with the *squad ammo* powers. What does that mean?

It means that if you take the increased capacity upgrades for squad members that you intend to use a squad ammo power with, **Shepard will benefit from it**.

Additionally, upgrades that effect *clip size* rather than total capacity will result in your squad members reloading less often, and by extension, higher damage output.

Answer (score 4):

They reload but they do not run out of ammo.

Comment: exactly, increased clip size will lower their reload times, which makes some difference

Comment: @yx. Clip size isn't the same as ammo capacity.

Comment: @kotsu I'm aware of that, even though your squad mates don't have ammo capacity, their weapons still have clip sizes

Comment: @yx. Is that relevant to this question though? OP is asking about ammo capacity upgrades, and I don't think there's a way to increase clip size in the game (at least in single player).

Comment: @kotsu weapon mods can increase clip size