# Is there a good way to determine squad mate cooldown time?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I was using James on a mission and noticed that it was taking his powers ages to cooldown.  Are the cooldown negatives and benefits for weight carried the same for squad mates as they are for Shepard?

Since he (James) totes around a shotgun and an assault rifle, it made some sense that he could be a bit slower, but is there a good way of managing this?  The annoying part is that you can't access squad character sheets when you're not on a mission, and you can't manage weapon load out when you are on a mission -unless you find a table.

***Is there a better way to see skill cooldowns and weapon load out at the same time?***

Comment: You're asking two different questions here. The one in your title, is a new and valid question, but your concerns regarding weight are [covered in this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54499/do-your-squad-members-have-a-weight-limit). The short answer is: Companions don't have a weight limit, so the weight of their weapons does not matter or affect the cooldown on their powers.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question - but if James is using his armor power ("Fortification" I believe), the ability text implies that it lengthens all his cooldowns. I know it does for Shepard when I took it as a bonus power, so I assume it would also apply to the squadmates as well. Haven't tested it, though.

Answer (score 3):

Companion Cooldowns are much longer than for Commander Shepard. He's just that good.

For comparison -- Shepard's Concussive Shot has a base cooldown of 5.58 - Garrus' is *10*, almost double. Weight has nothing to do with it - companions just take longer between abilities.

As to seeing when they're ready to be used, each ability (assuming you don't have Grenades on the companion) shares cooldowns, so whatever icon is on the hotbar will gray out during the cooldown period, gradually filling up from the bottom. When they're ready to be used again, the icon will flash white, then turn blue again, to let you know it's ready.