# Does weapon weight affect power recharge for squad mates?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do your squad members have a weight limit?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54499/do-your-squad-members-have-a-weight-limit)

I like equipping squad mates with the heavier, more powerful weapons - and using a shotgun+pistol myself. Does this affect their power recharge speed? Should I use light weight weapons for squad mates also, because I depend on powers a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, weapon weight does not affect power recharge for squad mates.